# Python/Django Calculate Expiration for Model

Tags: python, django, time

I have been unsuccessfully trying to calculate an expiration hour/minute for a Django model that I have. Here is the base code I am working with:

```
class Bribe(models.Model)
    date_offered = models.DateTimeField()

    def expiration(self):
        [...]
        return [Hours:Minutes until expiration]
```

My main goal is to calculate a countdown for how long a Bribe has until it will expire, in this case 48 hours. For example, if a Bribe has a `date_offered` value of `February 10th, 2015 @ 12:00PM`, I would like `def expiration(self)` to return a string of `12 hours 10 minutes remaining until expiration` if the current date is `February 11th 2015 @ 11:50PM`

If anyone can help me fill in what goes inside the function/method, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `timeuntil()` function which is used for the [`timeuntil`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#timeuntil) template filter:

```
from django.utils.timesince import timeuntil

def expiration(self):
    return timeuntil(self.date_offered)
```

Comment: Nice and follows DRY. I like this more than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to determine if my user was an adult (i.e., at least 18 years old). You should be able to manipulate it for your needs.

```
from datetime import date


def set_adult(self):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.date_of_birth.month, self.date_of_birth.day))
    if age >= 18:
      self.adult = True
    else:
      self.adult = False
```